# VS 2003 reference problem

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2003

We have inherited a vb.net 2003 web project, it seems to reference another web site. I am not sure how this was done. I cannot delete the reference (there is no properties and will not respond to pressing the delete key).
  The reference looks like a folder with a pic of the world on it. Any ideas how to get rid of it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case I don't believe you're referencing another web site.  Instead you're using a website which has a nested web site located under it.  This is a representation of IIS's internal structure and I don't believe you can change it via visual studio.  You'd have to delete the website in IIS.

Comment: I found http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WeirdGlobeFolderInVisualStudioWhenOpeningAWebProject.aspx.
Your are spot on getting it working, I have been cursing this thing all day.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a WebRefrences folder in SolutionExplorer (you may have to click Show All Files).
If so - you can delete the refrence there but you should check the all the code in the project (global search) to see if the code refrences the WebRefrence first.